# Navigate properties when using Dapper Extensions

Tags: c#, dapper

Im using DapperExtensions library for simple CRUD operations.
When I add a navigate property to my model, I get an error message that this column is not in the database. Can you in any way change this so that Dapper Extensions ignores this property?

Example of my model

```
public class Order : EntityBase
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int MarketId { get; set; }
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public decimal Undertaking { get; set; }

    public virtual Model Model { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Write attribute above the property

```
[Write(false)]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. add the package for dapperextentions
2. AutoMap(); will map all other properties as long as you have the same name for the field.

```
public class CustomMapper : DapperExtensions.Mapper.ClassMapper<Photo>
    {
        public CustomMapper()
        {
           Table("TableName if diffrent than the Model calss name");
           Map(f => f.SomePropertyIDontCareAbout).Ignore();
           AutoMap();
        }
    }
```